# Passing a Ci controller to a view

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope

How would I call a controller inside the view? When I use the code below, I'm limited with Html and CSS formatting. I could use jQuery JSON, but that's added work. Any ideas?

```
<?php
class home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function displayList() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            echo $row->title . "<br>";
            echo $row->text;
        }
    }
    function index() {
        $this->load->view('home');
        $data['lists'] = $this->displayList();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're supposed to call the view from the controller, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't call the controller in the view.  You pass the data from the controller to the view.

Like this:

```
function index() {
    $data = array();
    $data['lists'] = $this->displayList();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

Now in your `home` view, `$lists` will be the value of `displayList()`.

Also, `displayList` is `echo`ing out the data, not returning it so `$data['lists']` will be blank.  You should `return` the string, so the view can `echo` it.

```
function displayList() {
    $str = ''
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $str .= $row->title . "<br>" . $row->text;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

P.S. I usually put DB queries into a model, and have the controller call them.

Comment: I passed the array data to the view. But it still seems to be echoing out at the top of the screen which means it's not passing displayList() right... I can't get <?=$lists?> to work inside the view. It's not displaying anything in my div. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you change `displayList` to have it `return` the data instead of `echo`ing it?

Comment: `.` is the [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) operator in PHP.  `.=` is shorthand for `$a = $a.$str`.  You can do `$a .= $str` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You'll send an array of the stuff you want as the second argument to the `load->view`

```
$data['lists'] = $this->displayList();
$this->load->view('home',$data);
```

Now, you can access it in the view by using `$lists`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is this...

```
<?php
class home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function displayList() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            echo $row->title . "<br>";
            echo $row->text;
        }
    }

    function index() {
        $data = array();
        $data['lists'] = $this->displayList();
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
}

?>
```

then you can use `$lists` in the view to access that data

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about using the variables inside the view. thanks man.